# How to avoid loops in R?

Tags: r, social-networking

I'm dealing with a project with R. The project is, given a big data of edges between nodes, to test whether the test edges are true or not. As in the project, the basic element should be "edges", so that's how we can tell whether a given edge is real or not. So here comes the problem. we've create a data frame of two columns of "from" nodes and "to" nodes to indicate the edges, which is `edgesData` then we've created a graph from it using igraph, which is `graph`.We can calculate the similarity of two certain nodes, using

`similarity.jaccard(graph, vids = V(graph)[edgesData[1,1], edgesData[1,2]])`

But how can we get a table of all edges? I've tried

`similarity.jaccard(graph, vids = V(graph)[edgesData[,1], edgesData[,2]])`

but it didn't work. Also I've tried

`similarity.jaccard(graph, vids = E(graph))`

it didn't work either. An obvious way is to use loop, to retrieve each row from the data frame, but it seems to be a bad idea. So, Can anyone give me some advice? Thanks!

edit:
Ok it seems like the question is a bit confusing, so I've wrote a loop solution for it:

```
tpData <- edgesData
simList <- c()

while(nrow(tpData) > 0) {
  v1 <- tpData[1,1]
  v2 <- tpData[1,2]
  simList <- c(simList, similarity.jaccard(graph, V(graph)[v1, v2])[1,2])
  tpData <- tpData[-1,]
}
```

In this code I tried to get the two elements [,1], [,2] from each row, then calculate the similarity. Since the number of rows is near 20 million, so it takes forever to finish the job. There's got to be a better way to this. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe a reproducible example may help ?

Comment: I have no idea what it is you want, the jaccard-similarity is calculated between nodes (vertices) and not edges, you can get it from all nodes by simply typing: `similarity.jaccard(graph)` , you are constantly mixing up edges and vertices, so what is it you want??? you can get a list of all edges by typing `E(graph)`, but what kind of a table do you want?? are there multiple edges between the same set of vertices?? if no then a table of the edges makes 0 sense

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Here's what I have. I have a list of edges. Then I use it to create a graph. What I want is, to get the similarity of each pair of the nodes from the list.

Comment: it is impossible to get the similarity for each pair if you have ´that many nodes, even for just 100 nodes the number is 2^100 , there are just way too many combinations, so this task is impossible without any further restrictions to reduce the number of combinations drastically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most efficient way, but I've used it in the past myself. This is a simple example using dplyr:

```
    library(igraph)

    g <- graph.ring(5)

    data.frame(similarity.jaccard(g)) -> dt

    dt

#         X1        X2        X3        X4        X5
# 1 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
# 2 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333
# 3 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.3333333
# 4 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.0000000
# 5 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000 1.0000000

    library(dplyr)

    data.frame(expand.grid(1:nrow(dt),1:ncol(dt))) %>%    # combine all nodes (pairs)
      select(node1=Var1, node2=Var2) %>%                  # rename
      group_by(node1,node2) %>%                           # group in order to get each row separately
      do(data.frame(simil = dt[.$node1,.$node2])) %>%     # pick the corresponding similarities based on the nodes' pair
      ungroup

#    node1 node2     simil
# 1      1     1 1.0000000
# 2      1     2 0.0000000
# 3      1     3 0.3333333
# 4      1     4 0.3333333
# 5      1     5 0.0000000
# 6      2     1 0.0000000
# 7      2     2 1.0000000
# 8      2     3 0.0000000
# 9      2     4 0.3333333
# 10     2     5 0.3333333
# ..   ...   ...       ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the thing is, the number of vertices I have in the graph is about 4 millions. Can a data frame be that big?

Comment: Not sure but will definitely makes things slower. This could be solved if you have a specific objective. For example if you need to get pairs with similarity more than 0.8 you can reduce your combinations. However, with 4mil nodes you'll definitely get a massive data frame if you want similarity for all pairs. You have many combinations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem was I didn't chose the data set correctly.